# Bootstrap column stacks when data is filled in left one

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap nested grid.In one of my row I have 3 column. When I fill data in the first column of the row , then 3rd column of the row stacks down.However it stays good when there is no data.
Before filling Data:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="tagListDiv">
                  tags go here
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.DefaultImagePath)" alt="Image" height="150" width="150"/>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="color: #292929; background-color: #E3DAC9; vertical-align:bottom"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: #292929;background-color: #E3DAC9; vertical-align: bottom"></span>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Redered: [image: WithoutData]

After Filling Data:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="tagListDiv">
                    @for (var tagCount = 0; tagCount < @Model.TagList.Count(); tagCount++)
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                @(Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TagList.ToList()[tagCount].IsEnable))
                                <label>@Model.TagList.ToList()[tagCount].TagName</label>
                                @if (++tagCount == @Model.TagList.Count())
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                @(Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TagList.ToList()[tagCount].IsEnable))
                                <label>@Model.TagList.ToList()[tagCount].TagName</label>
                                @if (++tagCount == @Model.TagList.Count())
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                @(Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TagList.ToList()[tagCount].IsEnable))
                                <label>@Model.TagList.ToList()[tagCount].TagName</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

After data filled: 
[image: After Data is Filled]

Comment: can you set up a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) with the rendered html

Comment: Pete: Please find it here: http://www.bootply.com/oxOMuGrsfF

Comment: I need the image at bottom to the right of my tags grid.

Comment: Your code is outputting your structure like this: row -> col6 -> container fluid and then once inside this container fluid, you have your tagList, which doesnot have any col class, next to this you have a col2 and a col4.  Because your `#tagListDiv` doen't have a col class (try adding col-xs-6 to it), it is causing your image and col2 to drop down to the next line.  Or fix your structure so the output is like this: http://www.bootply.com/ttMbD7jAzz

Comment: Or fix your structure so the output is like this: http://www.bootply.com/ttMbD7jAzz - if you find the div `tagDivList`, remove the `container-fluid` direct parent div

Comment: If I do i that way then Image overflows to first column.Please find BitPly: http://www.bootply.com/oGI6iUZJoT

Comment: Thanks Pete !It worked , I had some js code which was not allowing dome div to be created on the fly.Your insight really helped me to fix it.